# jQuery test if element1 is descendant of element2

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know a good way to test if one element, stored in a var, is the descendant of another, also stored in a var?

I don't need `element1.isChildOf('selector')`, that's easy.
I need `element1.isChildOf(element2)`

`element2.find(element1).size() > 0` Does not seem to work.

I don't want to have to write a plugin the uses `.each` to test each child if I can avoid it.

Comment: If descendant is what you mean please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: This should be protected!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you're using 1.4, and are looking for a *descendant* rather than a child as your `find()` example implies, there's a [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method:

```
element2.has(element1).length > 0
```

Comment: `has()` checks works if something is a **descendant** and not a child as per the title.

Comment: You are correct. The `find()` example in the question misled me. Clarified.

Comment: Sorry, Descendant is what I'm after. I'll try this now. Cheers

Comment: Great, Thanks. I also found I did not need the `> 0` since `0 == false`

Comment: @Jake Beware with this asumption, especially with jQuery/-ui. For instance, `el.toggleClass('contains', el.has(el2))` would toggle your class with a short animation which could lead to performance problems. If you are using such shortcut out of a boolean context, you have to keep the `> 0` part, or cast it to a boolean value, e.g. with `!!`.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me, but the `.parents` solution below did

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for this. It will return -1 if an element isn't in the set. Assuming `element1` and `element2` are DOM elements and *not* jQuery objects:

```
if ($(element2).children().index(element1) != -1) {
  // it's a child
}
```

For completeness, to test if something is a *descendant* and not just a child, it can also be used for that too:

```
if ($(element1).parents().index(element2) != -1) {
  // element1 is a descendant of element2
}
```

Comment: The `.parents()` solution seems most efficient

Answer (score 6):

As of Jquery 1.6 you can determine whether a jquery object is a child of another jquery object this way:

```
element2.is(element1.children());
```

Also notable, since `is()` now accepts several different arguments (the first argument can be a function, jQuery selector, or DOM element), you can't think of the it simply as "is" anymore, but rather "is or is in".

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old but this also works if you want to check upwards not downwards:

```
function isElementChildOf(childElement, parentElement) {
    return 0 !== $(childElement).parents(parentElement).length;
}
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvRdR/)

Answer (score 1):

This is `true` if element1 is the child of element2, in other words element1 has a parent, that is element2

```
$(element1).parents(element2).length
```

this way it is **not OK**, if the parent has more children ([let say they are `input`'s](http://jsfiddle.net/4urnJ/1/)):

```
$(element2).children(element1).length
```