# Prevent overlay from closing when clicking select drop-down menu in form

Tags: jquery, html, overlay

my overlay script was working well until my client decided to add a form to one of the overlays. Now when you try filling in the form in Firefox and on mobile (Chrome works fine.) the select drop-down menu fields for month and year close the overlay. This happens when you try to select a date or year, not just clicking on it. Here my [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelsky/kxLy7zz6/) to demonstrate.

This is my code:

```
var hoverIntent;
var windowIsLarge;
jQuery(function($) {

windowIsLarge = $(document).width() > 769 ? true : false;

    $('.item').hover(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      if (windowIsLarge) {
        clearInterval(hoverIntent);
        $this = $(this);
            hoverIntent = setTimeout(function() {
        $this.find(".overlay").toggle();
            },600);
}else{
    $('.item').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(hoverIntent);
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find(".overlay").toggle();
       });
    }
});
});
```

How do I make it so the select menu doesn't close the overlay and you can fill out the form in Firefox and mobile?

Thanks!

John

Comment: can't you just check if overlay is visible in click handler? Otherwise can check target of click

Comment: Thanks, I'm rewriting this now, I'll try that. Was trying to do this with hover, but click is better for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few things up:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="overlay overlay1 hidden" value="1">Content 1
<form>
    <select>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
<div class="overlay overlay2 hidden" value="2">Content 2
    <form>
        <select>
            <option>option 1</option>
            <option>option 2</option>
            <option>option 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="overlay overlay3 hidden" value="3">Content 3</div>

<div class="item" value="1">Hover Me 1</div>
<div class="item" value="2">Hover Me 2</div>
<div class="item" value="3">Hover Me 3</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:140px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    width:620px;
    height:140px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid;
    top: 8px;
    left:0%;
    z-index:100;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    var selectOpened = false;
    $('select').click(function(e) {
        selectOpened = !selectOpened;
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('body').click(function() { if (selectOpened) selectOpened = false; });
    $('.item').mouseover(function() {
        $('.overlay' + $(this).attr('value')).removeClass('hidden');
    });
    $('.overlay').on('mouseleave', function() {
        if (!selectOpened) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/q4bm2hx6/


**Reference:** [Problem with jQuery mouseleave firing when container has select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212309/problem-with-jquery-mouseleave-firing-when-container-has-select-box)

It seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for your post, that seems to work well! I revised the script to use click instead of hover as we decided to switch to click. I also added a close button.         Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxhjxLy8/

Comment: JSHint says I'm missing a semicolon on this line: `$('body').click(function() { selectOpened = (selectOpened) ? false : true });` I'm not seeing why that is, any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: `selectOpened = (selectOpened) ? false : true` is a statement within an anonymous function. There should be a semicolon after it. Technically, at the current state, your close button won't work every other time you click the body. You should change that line to `if (selectOpened) selectOpened = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid firing `$('.item').click(function(e)` event when you select something from drop-down list

```
$('.item').click(function(e) {
        if(e.target == this) {
        e.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(hoverIntent);
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find(".overlay").toggle();
        }
       });
    }
```